# ContentResolver delete multiple

Tags: java, android, sql, android-calendar, android-contentresolver

I know a record can be deleted like this:

```
getContentResolver().delete(Events.CONTENT_URI, Events._ID + " =? ", eventId);
```

where eventId is a `String array` containing, in this case an event's ID.
In my case, I don't want to delete one event, but multiple. So I've got an array of eventIds containing multiple eventIds.
I could of course loop through the array and delete the events one by one, but is it also possible to delete them using just one call?

Comment: I believe you can create a batch of operations and then apply it calling `getContentResolver().applyBatch(uri_authority, batch)`

Comment: But will I be able to use a sql where clause?

Comment: I believe so. I'm trying to find my code that does something very similar. If I find it I'll post it here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code,

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> operationList = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
ContentProviderOperation contentProviderOperation;

for (/*loop over your arrayList*/) 
{
    contentProviderOperation = ContentProviderOperation.newDelete(Events.CONTENT_URI).withSelection(Events._ID + " =? ", new String[]{yourId}).build();
    operationList.add(contentProviderOperation);
}

try {
    getContentResolver().applyBatch(Contract.AUTHORITY, operationList);
} 
// catch the exceptions
```

More info: [ContentProviderOperation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProviderOperation.html)